# I am not getting any output for this python code

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

url = requests.get("https://www.pexels.com/search/flower/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

links = []

x = soup.select('img[src^="https://images.pexels.com/photos"]')

for img in x:
    links.append(img['src'])

for l in links:
    print(l)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: this site is protected by cloudflare

Comment: I am actually trying to scrape the website for pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `selenium` web driver to get all page sources then parse them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.pexels.com/search/flower/"

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver", options=options)

driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
links = []
x = soup.select('img[src^="https://images.pexels.com/photos"]')
for img in x:
    links.append(img['src'])
for l in links:
    print(l)
```

The last version of geckodriver [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

I got the following output:

```
https://images.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/3860667/pexels-photo-3860667.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/133472/pexels-photo-133472.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/4618416/pexels-photo-4618416.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/4234543/pexels-photo-4234543.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
...
https://images.pexels.com/photos/4492525/pexels-photo-4492525.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/4210784/pexels-photo-4210784.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
https://images.pexels.com/photos/4210781/pexels-photo-4210781.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
```

Comment: can you please explain to me why did you close the browser after getting the page source?

Comment: you're welcome! but instead this you can vote up my answer if it helped you:)